# MySQL : Huge table truncation in replication environment

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, master-slave-replication, truncate

We have 2 tables of size 186G and 63G that are no longer in use and needs to be truncated from the database.

I cannot directly run the truncate table statement on the master DB as it has 14 replicas dependent on it and it would cause a lag on the replicas as we have binlog row format set.

I tried deleting some records from the table but it is causing a lag on the replicas.

The master server is a busy server and receives read/write requests frequently.

Is there any way to perform this task without any impact/with minimum lag on the replicas.

Comment: in sql server I would remove those tables from the replication first, then truncate them in both publisher and subscribers. bear in mind for truncating all the foreign constraints need to be dropped, so if you use those tables for database integrity you might have to consider alternatives. I am not sure in `mysql`,I will have a look when someone replies to you.

Comment: Thank you Marcello, Yes I thought that ways i.e. to to remove it from the replication using the replica-ignore-table parameter in the mysql configuration file but that would involve a service restart. I believe this is the only option that I can do inorder to have minimum to no impact on the replicas.